Voltage Transformer Power Loss - What is the best regression form for a power loss vs frequency graph? What constants can I calculate?
I decided to investigate how power loss across a voltage transformer varies with frequency. I did this by measuring the voltages across the coils as well as the current in both the primary and the secondary side. From this I calculated the power loss (Method for which is described below). I identified three main areas of losses: Eddy currents, Hysteresis, and Winding resistance. From this I would expect the relationship to be quadratic (assuming skin effect is negligible, since the frequency range was only 25hz to 250hz). However since the voltage in the primary is constant, increasing the frequency increases the impedance, which decreases the current in turn decreasing the magnitude of the magnetic field present within the transformer core, which directly affects the power loss. I would appreciate it if someone would be able to help me figure out what form of regression should fit the power loss best according to the theory.
I also performed the same experiment again, however controlled the current to be constant, assuming that that would result in a frequency independent magnetic field, however I saw that the current in the secondary decreased with frequency. Since the secondary circuit also creates a magnetic field this means that the net magnetic field through the center was not frequency independent. Is this correct reasoning?
I also performed a no-load test at a constant current (which meant that the magnetic field was constant amplitude) which achieved results which would be as expected, following a quadratic relationship. However I do not not know what known value I could possibly calculate from the data and the regression to compare the accuracy of the experiment, since both hysteresis and eddy current losses are multiplied by a coefficient.
Data Processing
The sample rate I used was high enough for me to be able to perform sinusoidal regressions on the currents and voltages, in both the primary and secondary side. This allowed me to find the phase angle between the voltage and current on each side, which allowed me to calculate the true power in both the primary and secondary using the RMS voltage and RMS current. Then I subtracted the powers, to find the power difference, i.e. the power loss.
Here are photos of the data I found with a simple quadratic fit:

Constant Voltage:

Constant Current:
[
Constant Current No-Load test:


Final notes:
I do understand that the magnetic field is constantly changing. I mean to refer to the amplitude or rms value of the magnetic field.
